# UIButton doesn't change text color when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

UIButton created programatically doesn't change color when pressed, as all other buttons created using Interface Builder.

My button is created as follows:

```
        let cableDetailsButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        cableDetailsButton.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 42, 21)
        cableDetailsButton.setTitle("Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(self.view.tintColor, forState: .Normal)
        cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
        cableDetailsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FuseDetailsViewController.cableButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

I would like to add that tintColor is default iOS color (the blue one)

**My goal is to create programatically the same (default!) button as the one drag&dropped from the list in Interaface Builder. I want my button to change color/alpha upon pressing.**

I am using Swift 2.3

Unfortunately such simple task overwhelmed me to the extent to which I have to ask for help. Thank you in advance for help.

UPDATE: Button is part of UISCrollView

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
let cableDetailsButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
```

you need to change the `UIButtonType` as `.custom`

```
let cableDetailsButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
```

Also the syntax is incorrect if you are working on Swift3. Find the corrected syntax below

```
let cableDetailsButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
cableDetailsButton.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 42, height: 21)
cableDetailsButton.setTitle("Dane o przewodach", for: UIControlState.normal)
cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(self.view.tintColor, for: .normal)
cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState.highlighted)
cableDetailsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.cableButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: sorry, still doesn't work, button doesn't change to black upon click. I am using Swift 2.3

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
    let cableDetailsButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    cableDetailsButton.frame = CGRect(x: 68, y: 68, width: 100, height: 70)
    cableDetailsButton.setTitle("Some button", forState: .Normal)
    cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(self.view.tintColor, forState: .Normal)
    cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    view.addSubview(cableDetailsButton)
```

Or I did not completely understand what your question was.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working for me. I don't see black as I press the button.

Comment: yes, it is compiling. But it doesn't work. Button never changes color. tried on iOS 10 and iOS 9.3

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches to highlight button

**Approach 1**

```
   let cableDetailsButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    cableDetailsButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, self.view.frame.size.width - 32, 50)
    cableDetailsButton.setTitle("Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cableDetailsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cableButtonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cableDetailsButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(cableDetailsButton)

    func cableButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            if self.isHighLighted == false{
                sender.highlighted = true;
                self.isHighLighted = true
            }else{
                sender.highlighted = false;
                self.isHighLighted = false
            }
        });
    }
```

**Approach 2**

```
    let cableDetailsButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    cableDetailsButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, self.view.frame.size.width - 32, 50)
    cableDetailsButton.setTitle("Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.orangeColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    cableDetailsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cableButtonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(cableDetailsButton)


  func cableButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
        if sender.selected {
            // set selected
            sender.selected = true
        } else {
            // set deselected
            sender.selected = false
        }

    }
```

Comment: Button doesn't change the color during clicking. iOS 9.3 iPhone 6s emulator. Also it doens't compile in Swfit 2.3

Comment: I updated my answer please check and let me know whether it suits your requirement

Comment: First approach doesn't compile as ViewController doesn't contain property isHighLighted. Second approach compiles but doesn't work. The only strange thing that happened was that on FIRST click, the button's alpha changed so that it behaved like normal one. What's strange, it didn't change color to orange at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. implement a flag in your view controller

   ```
   var buttonSelected = false
   ```
2. keep your code for your button but remove one line

   ```
   let cableDetailsButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
   cableDetailsButton.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 42, 21)
   cableDetailsButton.setTitle("Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(self.view.tintColor, forState: .Normal)
   cableDetailsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FuseDetailsViewController.cableButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   ```
3. in your targeted function add the following

   ```
   func cableButtonPressed() {
       if buttonSelected {
          cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(self.view.tintColor, forState: .Normal)
          buttonSelected = !buttonSelected
          //do whatever else you need to do
       } else {
          cableDetailsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
          buttonSelected = !buttonSelected
          //do whatever else you need to do
       }
       //do whatever else you need to do
   }
   ```

Comment: Create a global variable for a UI element state? No way...